# Highcharts - restrict sankey diagram to only one level

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I have a Sankey diagram in highcharts and I want to restrict it to only one level - meaning if I have a connection ITEM1-ITEM2 and then another one ITEM2-ITEM3, I want the diagram to create a new node ITEM2 on the left, instead of connected the already existing ITEM2 node.

ex:

```
data: [
  [['item1','item2', 'item3'], 'res', 5 ],
  ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1 ],
  ['Canada', 'France', 5 ],
  ['USA', 'England', 5 ],
  ['England', 'Germany', 3]
],
```

see JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/morn2e4g/7/

Comment: But then it's no longer a Sankey diagram, and is simply a bar chart with various width, no?

Comment: This functionality cannot be achieved by using chart options. Highcharts is a library that serves rather to displaying the data than processing it. You should preprocess your data before passing it to the chart constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic way to achieve this is by appending a space to the end of all of the "from" labels (and never to the "to" labels). ex:

```
data: [
  [['item1','item2', 'item3'], 'res', 5 ],
  ['Canada ', 'Portugal', 1 ],
  ['Canada ', 'France', 5 ],
  ['USA ', 'England', 5 ],
  ['England ', 'Germany', 3]
],
```